# Cannot see div which is hidden by a canvas

Tags: html, css

I've coded a simple code, in which I try to see a div. But it is hidden by the canvas. why is that?
Even `z-index` did not do the job. How can I make the `TEST` div visible?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                position: relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        
            .canvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
              z-index: 2;
            }
            
            .test {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                padding: 10px;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            
            .testInner {
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              color: white;
              z-index: 50;
              }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
            <div class="test">
              <div class="testInner">
                TEST
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
          const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
          const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.lineWidth="20"
          ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
          ctx.stroke();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You never closed your canvas. Add the `</canvas>` and it will work like below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                position: relative;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        
            .canvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            
            .test {
                position: absolute;
                background-color: red;
                color: white;
                padding: 10px;

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
            
        <div class="test">TEST</div></div>
        
        <script>
          const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
          const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
          ctx.lineTo(200, 200);
          ctx.stroke();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this case, z-index is not needed.

Comment: I edited the Q. now - although I set the `z-index` of `.testInner` to high value, the text is hidden by the canvas. why?

Comment: @ShalviMuqta What are you talking about? It works for me.

Comment: As I run the new code, the canvas line covers the text

Comment: @ShalviMuqta When I run the snippet, it works just fine.

Comment: can you send a screenshot?  because this is what I see lol: https://prnt.sc/uudjv0